# What does apiserver_request_duration_seconds prometheus metric in Kubernetes mean?

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus, metrics

I want to know if the apiserver_request_duration_seconds accounts the time needed to transfer the request (and/or response) from the clients (e.g. kubelets) to the server (and vice-versa) or it is just the time needed to process the request internally (apiserver + etcd) and no communication time is accounted for ?

As a plus, I also want to know where this metric is updated in the apiserver's HTTP handler chains ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How long API requests are taking to run. Whole thing, from when it starts the HTTP handler to when it returns a response.

Comment: OK great that confirms the stats I had because the average request duration time increased as I increased the latency between the API server and the Kubelets. Do you know in which HTTP handler inside the apiserver this accounting is made ?

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the confirmation of @coderanger in the accepted answer. The metric is defined [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/5978856c4c7f10737a11c9540fe60b8475beecbb/staging/src/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/endpoints/metrics/metrics.go#L84) and it is called from the function MonitorRequest which is defined [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/5978856c4c7f10737a11c9540fe60b8475beecbb/staging/src/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/endpoints/metrics/metrics.go#L255). The former is called from a chained route function InstrumentHandlerFunc [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/5978856c4c7f10737a11c9540fe60b8475beecbb/staging/src/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/endpoints/metrics/metrics.go#L293) which is itself set as the first route handler [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/5978856c4c7f10737a11c9540fe60b8475beecbb/staging/src/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/endpoints/installer.go#L659) (as well as other places) and chained with [this function](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/5978856c4c7f10737a11c9540fe60b8475beecbb/staging/src/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/endpoints/installer.go#L1081), for example, to handle resource LISTs in which the internal logic is finally implemented [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/5978856c4c7f10737a11c9540fe60b8475beecbb/staging/src/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/endpoints/handlers/get.go#L166) and it clearly shows that the data is fetched from `etcd` and sent to the user (a blocking operation) then returns back and does the accounting.